# search through the search box from front end, by passing many keywords

Tags: php, sql

Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_GET['go'])){
        $key1 = trim($_POST['key']);
        $key2 = preg_replace("#[\s]+#", " ", $key1);
        $key = explode(" ", $key2);
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");

        if (!$con) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db("productdetails", $con);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($key); $i++){     
            $result = mysql_query("select * from proddetail where pname like '%".$key[$i]."%' or pcolor like '%".$key[$i]."%' or  psize LIKE '%".$key[$i]."%' or  mrp LIKE '%".$key[$i]."%' or  saleprize LIKE '%".$key[$i]."%' OR  pType LIKE '%".$key[$i]."%' or warranty LIKE '%".$key[$i]."%' or imagename LIKE '%".$key[$i]."%' or pKey LIKE '%".$key[$i]."%' GROUP by pname");
```

The above code selects some rows. When I pass the arguments **mobile black color** it shows all color mobiles.

But expected result needs only mobiles which are all in black color, it should reject other colors.

Comment: Please add your database/table schema to your question.

Comment: pkey   pname   mfg   psize   mrp   saleprize   pType  pcolor   warranty  imagename

Answer (score 0):

May This Suggestion Help You.

In Sql query has You Checked your key To every Field OF the table And You used A %.% So what happen your search string every letter match with all the field so Possibility is  Maximum to match to every field of table so it display all the mobile.

if you Search the "**Black**" Then If color is black that mobile display and also if any mobile name is black also that display but that mobile color is not black.

so You can not search throw this query.

If made easy if you categorizes search Like a search by name,color also prize etc.